# Coefficient of the Highest Degree in the Power Series Solution to Legendre's Differential Equation

Tags: linear-algebra, power-series, legendre-polynomials

The Legendre's differential equation
$$(1-x^2)y''-2xy'+n(n+1)y=0$$

Substitute $y=\sum_{m=0}^\infty a_mx^m$
$$
\sum_{m=2}^\infty m(m-1)a_mx^{m-2}-\sum_{m=2} ^\infty m(m-1)a_mx^m-\sum_{m=1}^\infty 2ma_mx^m+\sum_{x=0}^\infty ka_mx^m=0\\
$$
Set $m=s+2$
$$
\sum_{s=0}^\infty (s+2)(s+1)a_{s+2}x^s-\sum_{s=2}^\infty s(s-1)a_sx^s-\sum_{s=1}^\infty 2sa_sx^s+\sum_{s=0}^\infty ka_sx^s=0\\
\implies \boxed{ a_{s+2}=\frac{-(n-s)(n+s+1)}{(s+2)(s+1)}a_s }\\
\implies y(x)=a_0y_1(x)+a_1y_2(x)\\
$$
where
$$
y_1(x)=1-\frac{n(n+1)}{2!}x^2+\frac{(n-1)n(n+1)(n+3)}{4!}x^4-\cdots\\
y_2(x)=x-\frac{(n-1)(n+2)}{3!}x^3+\frac{(n-3)(n-1)(n+2)(n+4)}{5!}x^5-\cdots\\
$$
When $n=s\geq 0$, we have $a_{n+2}=a_{n+4}=\cdots=0$

$$
a_{n-2}=\frac{-n(n-1)}{2(2n-1)}a_n\\
a_{n-4}=\frac{-(n-2)(n-3)}{4(2n-3)}a_{n-2}=(-1)^2\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}{2.4(2n-1)(2n-3)}a_n
$$
and so on

It is said that the Legendre polynomials are defined by choosing $\color{red}{a_n=\frac{(2n-1)(2n-3)\cdots3.1}{n!}=\frac{(2n)!}{2^n(n!)^2}}$

I think it comes from $P_n(1)=1$ but how do I derive it from the recurrence relation here ?

**My Attempt**

$$
a_{n-2m}=(-1)^{m}\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-(2m-1))}{2.4.\cdots 2m.(2n-1)(2n-3)\cdots(2n-(2m-1))}a_n\\
$$

Set $n=2m$ and $P_0(1)=a_0=1$
$$
a_0=(-1)^{m}.\frac{n!}{2^m.m!.(2n-1)(2n-3)\cdots(n+1)}.a_n\\
a_n=(-1)^{m}.\frac{2^m.m!.(2n-1)(2n-3)\cdots(n+1)}{n!}.a_0\\
=(-1)^{m}.\frac{2^m.m!.(2n-1)(2n-3)\cdots(n+1).(n-1)(n-3)\cdots 5.3.1}{n!.(n-1)(n-3)\cdots 5.3.1}.a_0\\
=(-1)^{m}.\color{red}{ \frac{(2n-1)(2n-3)\cdots3.1}{n!} }.\frac{2^m.m!}{(n-1)(n-3)\cdots 5.3.1}.1
$$
I don't think my derivation is leading to the required choice of the coefficient of the highest degreee. How do I approch the problem then ?

**Reference:** [link](http://egyankosh.ac.in/bitstream/123456789/19441/1/Unit-14.pdf)

[image: pic]

Comment: So  in your attempt, for example,  $a_2 <0$

Comment: @A.PI yes. Even if I ignore the sign, there seems to be more terms other than what is given the choice for $a_n$

Comment: The recurrence equation that you found above gives the coefficients of the polynomial solution to the DE. Since the Legendre polynomials are defined such that $P_n(1) =1,$ The SUM of the coefficients up to the higher degree should give you $\frac{2^n (n!)^2}{(2n)!}.$

Comment: @A.PI Thats what I am trying t prove here. How does the condition $P_n(1)=1$ implies $a_n=\frac{2^n(n!)^2}{(2n)!}$ ?

Comment: It's not the $a_n$ but this sum $1- \sum_{k=1}^p \frac{(-1)^k(n)(n-1)\cdots (n-2k+1)}{2^k k! (2n -1)(2n-3)\cdots(2n-2k+1)}.$ Here I considered WLOG $n =2p.$

Comment: @A.PI In the reference that I mentioned, it is said that "The Legendre polynomials $P_n(x)$ are defined by choosing $a_n=\frac{(2n)!}{2^n(n!)^2}$" ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117121/discussion-between-a-pi-and-ss1729).

Comment: I'm going through the same doubts as you. Maybe it's a little too late to ask for this but did you managed to get a way to prove this coefficient choice was the necessary one? Or did you had to take the leap of faith 'because it works'? Hope you see this.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I'll post what I've done in order to justify the $a_n$ coefficient selection. Hopefully this will be of help for some future people looking for some insight.

From (14.7) we see that the general term takes the form:

$$(-1)^r\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3) \cdots (n-(2r-1))}{2\cdot 4 \cdot 6 \cdots (2r) \cdot (2n-1)(2n-3)(2n-5) \cdots(2n-(2r-1))}x^{n-2r}
=
(-1)^r\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3) \cdots (n-(2r-1))}{2^{r}r! \cdot (2n-1)(2n-3)(2n-5) \cdots(2n-(2r-1))}x^{n-2r}$$

Where

$$n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3) \cdots (n-2r+1)=n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3) \cdots (n-2r+1)\cdot \frac{(n-2r)!}{(n-2r)!}=\frac{n!}{(n-2r)!}$$

and

$$(2n-1)(2n-3)(2n-5) \cdots (2n-2r+1) = 
\frac{\color{red}{(2n)}(2n-1)\color{red}{(2n-2)}(2n-3)\color{red}{(2n-4)}(2n-5)\color{red}{(2n-6)} \cdots \color{red}{(2n-2r+2)!}(2n-2r+1)\cdot\color{red}{(2n-2r)!}}{\color{red}{\color{red}{(2n)(2n-2)(2n-4)(2n-6)} \cdots (2n-2r+2)!\cdot\color{red}(2n-2r)!}}=
\frac{(2n)!}{2(n)2(n-1)2(n-2) \cdots 2(n-r+1) (2n-2r)!}=
\frac{(2n)!}{2^{r}n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-r+1)(2n-2r)!}=
\frac{(2n)!}{2^{r}\frac{n!}{(n-r)!}(2n-2r)!}=
\frac{(2n)!(n-r)!}{2^{r}n!(2n-2r)!}
$$

Then:

$$(-1)^r\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3) \cdots (n-(2r-1))}{2^{r}r! \cdot (2n-1)(2n-3)(2n-5) \cdots(2n-(2r-1))}x^{n-2r}
=
(-1)^r\frac{1}{2^{r}r!}\frac{n!}{(n-2r)!}x^{n-2r}\frac{2^{r}n!(2n-2r)!}{(2n)!(n-r)!}
=
(-1)^r\frac{1}{r!}\frac{(n!)^2}{(n-2r)!}\frac{(2n-2r)!}{(2n)!(n-r)!}x^{n-2r}$$

And therefore (14.7) can be expressed as:

$$y=a_n \sum_{r \geq 0}(-1)^r \frac{(n!)^2 (2n-2r)!}{r! (2n)!(n-r)!(n-2r)!}x^{n-2r}$$

Now, we are looking for an $a_n$ coefficient such that $y(1)=1$, which means:

$$1=a_n \sum_{r \geq 0}(-1)^r \frac{(n!)^2 (2n-2r)!}{r! (2n)!(n-r)!(n-2r)!}
=
a_n\frac{(n!)^2 }{(2n)!} \sum_{r \geq 0}(-1)^r \frac{(2n-2r)!}{r!(n-r)!(n-2r)!}
$$

Where the sum can be expressed as:

$$\sum_{r \geq 0}(-1)^r \frac{(2n-2r)!}{r!(n-r)!(n-2r)!}
=
\sum_{r \geq 0}(-1)^r \frac{\color{red}{n!}}{r!(n-r)!} \frac{(2n-2r)!}{(n-2r)!\color{red}{n!}}
=
\sum_{r \geq 0}(-1)^r {n \choose r}{2n-2r \choose n}
$$

In this last expression, each term is non zero if and only if
$$2n-2r \geq n \implies r \leq \frac{n}{2}$$

In other words, $r$ runs from $0$ to $\frac{n}{2}$ if $n$ is even, or from $0$ to $\frac{n-1}{2}$ if $n$ is odd.

Ok, now we want to know the value of  $\sum_{r \geq 0}(-1)^r {n \choose r}{2n-2r \choose n}$. For this we use the binomial expansion of $[(1+x)^2-1]^n$.

$$[(1+x)^2-1]^n = \sum_{r=0}^{n} {n \choose r}(1+x)^{2(n-r)}= \sum_{r=0}^{n} {n \choose r}(1+x)^{2n-2r} = \sum_{r=0}^{n} {n \choose r}\left[ \sum_{k=0}^{2n-2r} {2n-2r \choose k}(1)^{2n-2r-k}x^k     \right](-1)^r$$

$$\therefore [(1+x)^2-1]^n = \sum_{r=0}^{n} (-1)^r{n \choose r}\left[ \sum_{k=0}^{2n-2r} {2n-2r \choose k}x^k \right]$$

Here the coefficient of the $x^n$ occurs when $k=n$, or:

$$\sum_{r=0}^{n} (-1)^r{n \choose r}{2n-2r \choose n}$$
is the $x^n$ coefficient.

On the other hand, we can express $[(1+x)^2-1]^n$ as:
$$[(1+x)^2-1]^n =[1+2x+x^2-1]^n=[2x+x^2]^n=x^n\color{red}{[2+x]^n}$$

And here, the $x^n$ coefficient can be expressed, again, in the binomial form:

$$\sum_{r=0}^{n} {n\choose r} 2^{n-r}x^r$$

When $r=0$ the resulting expression corresponds to the $x^n$ coefficient. Then:

$${n\choose 0} 2^{n-0}x^0 = 1 \cdot 2^n \cdot 1 = 2^n$$

So we can equal both $x^n$ coefficients obtaining:

$$\sum_{r=0}^{n} (-1)^r{n \choose r}{2n-2r \choose n} = 2^n$$

But we can argue in a similar way as before that this sum runs from $0$ to $\frac{n}{2}$ for $n$ even or $\frac{n-1}{2}$ for $n$ odd.

Finally (yes, finally) we have that:

$$1=a_n \sum_{r \geq 0}(-1)^r \frac{(n!)^2 (2n-2r)!}{r! (2n)!(n-r)!(n-2r)!}
=
a_n\frac{(n!)^2 }{(2n)!} \sum_{r \geq 0}(-1)^r \frac{(2n-2r)!}{r!(n-r)!(n-2r)!}
=
a_n\frac{(n!)^2 }{(2n)!} 2^n
$$
And:

$$a_n=\frac{(2n)!}{2^n (n!)^2}$$
Is the value of the $a_n$ coefficient we were looking for ☺.

And now we can state that the Legendre polynomial can be expressed as:

$$P_{n}(x)=\frac{(2n)!}{2^n (n!)^2} \sum_{r \geq 0}(-1)^r \frac{(n!)^2 (2n-2r)!}{r! (2n)!(n-r)!(n-2r)!}x^{n-2r} = \sum_{r=0}^{\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor}(-1)^r \frac{(2n-2r)!}{2^n r!(n-r)!(n-2r)!}x^{n-2r}$$
where
$$\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor= 
\begin{cases}   
  \frac{n}{2} & \text{, n even} \\ \frac{n-1}{2}  & \text{, n odd}
\end{cases}$$